# Returning data outside axios async call

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, axios

How do I return value of `stuff` outside the for loop. I need to make an API call `i` amount of times and store the result each time. There is probably a duplicate question somewhere with the answer but I am unable to find it.

```
function getResponse() {
    var stuff = []
    
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        axios.get(url + i)
            .then(res => res.forEach(item => {
                stuff.push(item)
            }))
    }
    // How do I return stuff from this function ?
}

console.log(getResponse())
```

I've tried making this function only do a call and then looping in another function which calls this but I get:

> cannot read property then of undefined.

Comment: There you are :) if there are further questions, things that you can't get to work, don't hesitate to ask :)

Comment: Thanks, I'm working through that right now.

Comment: @JonasW. How would I do something right outside the forEach loop? Let's say I have another variable `allStuff` and after I have populated `stuff` I want to set `allStuff = stuff`.

Comment: The problem is that the axios calls are arriving from the server *after* all the code executed. You have to `await` those calls and then you can work with their data.

Comment: I've tried async/await but I am on an older version of node that doesn't support it

Comment: Then either update or use Promises only.

Comment: How do I "use Promises only"? Would you look at my problem in chat?

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call to understand the problem, i will add a solution for you in the meantime...

Comment: I suppose the issue I'm having is I am making multiple async calls within a loop and must wait until all of them are complete.

Comment: Exactly! :) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I return stuff from this function ?

You can't. Its like "I want to get the newspaper of tomorrow". That won't work either. You have to wait until the next day to read the newspaper, or in your case, until all the data arrived at the browser. You cannot return the data directly, but a *Promise* that will deliver the data somewhen. In your case you can use `Promise.all` to unify an array of promises into a promise that resolves to an array:

```
function getResponse() {
  const promises = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    promises.push(axios.get(url + i));
  }

  return Promise.all(promises)
    .then(results => [].concat(...results));
}
```

So now if you do:

```
console.log(getResponse())
```

You get a promise. To get the actual data, you have to wait until the data arrives:

```
getResponse().then(console.log);
```

Comment: Ok let me try to understand this

Comment: Ok I am making some progress, thanks. I will comment back if I run into any more issue and give you a green check

Comment: @vincent take your time, this is one of the most complicated things in javascript. I'm glad to help :)

Comment: I am used to Vue/React where I can just make the call and set a variable to display, but this is a new problem for me because I just need the data

Comment: Okay, I'm really close now. The only problem I have now is still, how do I   return variable after `getResponse().then...` What I have is two `forEach` inside `getResponse().then(forEach...)` and I push to `stuff` but not sure how to return `stuff` outside the `then` it comes back as empty

Comment: Can't I return another promise with that variable and print in another function?

Comment: Never mind, I just used an index to catch the last iteration of the `forEach` and logged my final result there. Thanks for all your help